# Excluding posts with certain value of meta_key keeping posts without that meta_key

Tags: wp-query, custom-field

There are solutions for this problem, but what I could found, all of them are from long ago. So I am looking for a solution (if there is any) considering recent updates.

I have a meta key `wpse_city`, which is a radio button with several values. Now I want to exclude posts with `wpse_city = 'dhaka'` but I also want to show posts which doesn't have `wpse_city` key. So this is how I am doing this:

```
$args['meta_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'wpse_city',
        'value' => 'dhaka',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'wpse_city',
        'value' => 'dhaka',
        'compare' => '!=',
    )
);
```

Am I doing it correctly? Is there any other better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it - it's just a problem with logic. What you're basically saying is "get posts that don't have this meta key, or where this meta key isn't equal to 'dhaka'". The problem is, posts without that meta key at all... also aren't equal to 'dhaka', so therefore they match!

You can fix this with a nested meta_query, using an AND relation, to check that the key also exists if you're going to compare what it isn't equal to. Like this:

```
$args['meta_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'wpse_city',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
          'key' => 'wpse_city',
          'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        array(
          'key' => 'wpse_city',
          'value' => 'dhaka',
          'compare' => '!=',
        )
    )
);
```

You also don't need to provide a value anymore when you're using EXISTS and NOT EXISTS - this was due to an old bug. See the [WP_Meta_Query documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Accepted_Arguments) for more information on this.

Comment: Thanks. "The problem is, posts without that meta key at all... also aren't equal to 'dhaka'" - is this true? Because, my query actually returns correct posts!

Comment: @тнєSufi It does? Why did you ask then? ;) I thought you were saying it wasn't working. That's good then - although I would personally still make it more explicit with a nested query as in my answer, to help protect against any esoteric bugs that might pop up. There have been bugs with meta_query before so I prefer to make it really clear what I want to query. It also has the bonus of making the code more readable too.